# How to bring scroll bar/view in top position?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

scrollbar

tableLayout
**My view data**
/tableLayout

/scrollbar

I showed the data.. when I m in last row of view, once my UI is updated I want to bring scroll to the top position.

What should be code that I need to be done for this action. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

OR

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

call listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView(); to scroll to top

Answer (score 0):

you may, do like this

```
int idx = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View vfirst = list.getChildAt(0);
int pos = 0;
if (vfirst != null) pos = vfirst.getTop();

//Restore the position
list.setSelectionFromTop(idx, pos);
```